# When I click on the minimize button (-) of the last running window nothing happens

Tags: 20.04

I recently installed ubuntu focal 20.04; When I click on the minimize button (-) of the last running window nothing happens? I also have Dash-to-Panel extension enabled.

for example, here I minimized all the running apps and only Terminal is on the desktop but it is frozen and I can't do anything:

[image]

Comment: This is difficult to reproduce for me.

Comment: Does it happen for all Windows? Can you disable all the extensions and try again? Please edit the question to add more details.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no only for the last window.

Comment: What happens if you hit Super+H? Super is the OS-themed key usually between Ctrl & Alt.